# Google AppEngine: basic Spring MVC 4 REST + JSON works in dev but not in prod

Tags: java, json, rest, google-app-engine, spring-mvc

I have a very basic Spring MVC 4 REST + JSON demo that I'm trying to get running on Google AppEngine and I'm unable to get past a "406 Not Acceptable" response from the code in production. The same code works happily on the AppEngine dev server.

my appEngine dev server Responds to this request:
http://localhost:8080/service/greeting/getGreeting

with this response:

```
{"id":1,"content":"Hello, World!"}
```

But deploying the same to appEngine production results in a '406 Not Acceptable'.

Looking at the details using my Chrome Advanced REST Client gives me this on local:

```
Status
200 OK Show explanation Loading time: 13
Request headers 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.99 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: dev_appserver_login=test@example.com:false:18580476422013912411
Response headers 
Content-Type: application/json 
Server: Development/1.0 
Date: Sat, 24 Jan 2015 22:57:33 GMT 
Cache-Control: no-cache 
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT 
Content-Length: 34
```

But this on prod:

```
Status
406 Not Acceptable Show explanation Loading time: 487
Request headers 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.99 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Response headers 
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 
Content-Encoding: gzip 
Vary: Accept-Encoding 
Date: Sat, 24 Jan 2015 22:56:19 GMT 
Server: Google Frontend 
Cache-Control: private 
Content-Length: 170 
Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic,p=0.02
```

The obvious difference that I can see being the Content-type from prod:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

.. But if that is the problem, I have no idea what to do about it. My method is annotated to create "application/json", but it's almost as if that's being ignored in prod.
I've confirmed that all the Jackson jars are in the resulting WAR file too.

The actual error as listed in the AppEngine logs is this:

```
09:47:33.982 2015-01-25  406 244 B 8ms /service/greeting/getGreeting
124.169.143.81 - - [24/Jan/2015:14:47:33 -0800] "GET /service/greeting/getGreeting HTTP/1.1" 406 244 - "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.99 Safari/537.36" "spring-mvc-test-zone.appspot.com" ms=8 cpu_ms=324 cpm_usd=0.000027 instance=00c61b117cb1cb2dbcd014386050a9f83a53 app_engine_release=1.9.17
```

Any hints?

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <groupId>com.bluemongo.springMvcTest</groupId>
    <artifactId>springMvcTest</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <appengine.app.version>4</appengine.app.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>4.1.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.1.0</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.objectify</groupId>
            <artifactId>objectify</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- Test Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!-- for hot reload of the web application-->
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>display-dependency-updates</goal>
                            <goal>display-plugin-updates</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                    <webResources>
                        <!-- in order to interpolate version from pom into appengine-web.xml -->
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <enableJarClasses>false</enableJarClasses>
                    <!-- Comment in the below snippet to bind to all IPs instead of just localhost -->
                    <!-- address>0.0.0.0</address>
                    <port>8080</port -->
                    <!-- Comment in the below snippet to enable local debugging with a remove debugger
                         like those included with Eclipse or IntelliJ -->
                    <!-- jvmFlags>
                      <jvmFlag>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n</jvmFlag>
                    </jvmFlags -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My Controller:

```
package com.bluemongo.springMvcTest.controller;

import com.bluemongo.springMvcTest.model.Greeting;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/service/greeting")
public class RestGreetingController {
    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

@RequestMapping( value = "/getGreeting", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers="Accept=application/json", produces = {"application/json"})
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)

    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name));
        //return "Sending a String was successful";
    }
}
```

My model:

```
package com.bluemongo.springMvcTest.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Greeting implements Serializable{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1576547040362820422L;
    private final long id;
    private final String content;

    public Greeting(long id, String content) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public static long getSerialVersionUID() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }
}
```

my dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd

        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd

        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

    <bean class="com.bluemongo.springMvcTest.controller.HelloWorldController"></bean>
    <bean class="com.bluemongo.springMvcTest.controller.AnotherController"></bean>
    <bean class="com.bluemongo.springMvcTest.controller.RestGreetingController"></bean>

<!--    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="1" />
    <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
        </map>
    </property>
        <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
        &lt;!&ndash; JSON View &ndash;&gt;
        <bean
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView">
        </bean>
        </list>
        </property>
    </bean>-->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <!--  <mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="contentManager"/>
       <bean id="contentManager"
              class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="favorPathExtension" value="true"/>
            <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
            <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json" />
            <property name="useJaf" value="false"/>
            <property name="mediaTypes">
                <map>
                    <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
                    <entry key="html" value="text/html" />
                    <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
                </map>
            </property>
        </bean>-->

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        <property name="order"  value="3"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Configure to plugin JSON as request and response in method handler -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Configure bean to convert JSON to POJO and vice versa -->
    <bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Have you succeeded in solving this? I'm pretty stuck in a similar point :)

Comment: Hi @StasS, what I ended up doing was building my own environment using Google Compute Engine rather than using AppEngine. The same code works fine in GCE. I assumed it was some limitation of AppEngine that I hadn't found documented.

Answer (score 2):

You should explicitly define in your client that you only accept application/json. So for the Chrome Advanced REST Client be sure to set the Accept header to be Accept=application/json instead of Accept=*/*.

Comment: Hi @BrianReindel, thanks for the response. The Accept header doesn't seem to be configurable within the Chrome REST Client, and anyway, the dev output with the same Accept header works fine from the same client. Does that rule that out? Also referencing http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html
"The request will be matched only if the Accept request header matches one of these values. Furthermore, use of the produces condition ensures the actual content type used to generate the response respects the media types specified in the produces condition."

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is what is different between your local and prod environments? This can be a couple different things. Does your servlet container (Tomcat, JBoss, Websphere, etc.) have libraries already deployed globally on the classpath that are causing conflicts with what is in your deployed artifact? Also, is Apache sitting in between, or some other web server that is manipulating the headers in the request or response somehow?

Comment: Thanks @BrianReindel, I'm actually using the default appEngine dev server, that comes with the appEngine SDK (I believe it's based on Jetty). I'm sure I'm making some n00b mistake somewhere, but I just can't see it  :)